# Magnetic braking for interplanetary journeys?

Tags: interplanetary, magnetic-field

One proposed use for a [magnetic sail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_sail) is to allow an interstellar spacecraft to brake as it approaches its destination. But could a magnetic sail also slow down a spacecraft traveling between planets? To be clear, I'm not talking about braking against planetary magnetospheres (as mentioned in [Magnetic / Inductive braking against planetary magnetic fields?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20804/12102)), but braking against the interplanetary medium.

If it worked, it could potentially save a lot of fuel, since spacecraft normally need to expend fuel to decelerate as well as to accelerate, leading to better mass ratios.

If this wouldn't be practical with a conventional magnetic sail, then would it be practical with something like the [plasma magnet drive](https://www.centauri-dreams.org/2017/12/29/the-plasma-magnet-drive-a-simple-cheap-drive-for-the-solar-system-and-beyond/) instead?

Comment: If there is only a very weak magnetic field in the interplanetary space, magnetic braking will be very weak too.

Comment: I understand that "magsails" have been proposed as a means of solar-wind-driven interplanetary travel.

Comment: @Uwe My question is specifically about braking using the interplanetary medium, not about braking using any magnetic fields (other than that of the magnetic sail itself).

Comment: If you want to ask "about braking using the interplanetary medium", you should not ask "Magnetic braking for...".